# Can't add file cause of different case filename in git

Tags: git

I want to run: `git add <folder>` and there are several files that have **different contents** and **same file name with different cases**.

For example, they may be `dir/DiffCONTENT.mk` and `dir/diffcontent.mk`. Remember, they have different content and same file name with different case only.

When I `git add dir/`, I got an error:

```
fatal: Will not add file alias 'dir/DiffCONTENT.mk' ('dir/diffcontent.mk' already exists in index)
```

Even I tried `git --all --ignore-errors --force dir/`, I still can't solve this.
I can not change file name one by one, I even don't know how many files with same case were there.

Comment: You have to change the filenames, git will refuse to add them otherwise as you have noticed. There should be no way to force this.

Comment: But I don't understand. Isn't git hashes content only? Why it checks file's name? Even they are DIFFERENT cases?

Answer (score 2):

Git is case-sensitive but I think your filesystem is not.

Maybe you can set this to true :

```
    core.ignorecase

 If true, this option enables various workarounds
 to enable git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive,
 like FAT. For example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when git expects 
"Makefile", git will assume it is really the same file, and continue to remember
 it as "Makefile".

 The default is false, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probeand set 
 core.ignorecase true if appropriate when the repository is created.
```

But I think you'd be better off renaming your files with a quick script.

Comment: My problem is: They are **DIFFERENT** case with different content files.
My OS is ubuntu 12.04, should not be the problem with cases. Different case file name is different file of course. So git should not care about the file name. That's too unusual.

Comment: I understand, however I really think [git-add uses file names](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). In your case git considers there are several files with the same name